# ACF select filed translation via qTranslate

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

Those who use these plugins know that you can translate some of ACF fields via qTranslate (text, text area, etc). But I need on my website translate also select field with options. So any advise?
I was looking for other plugin options, like `Polylang` which offers registration of `pll_register_string()` in `function.php`. But migrating to `Polylang` may be will consume more time.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall there's a WordPress dedicated subsite here on StackExchange for such questions; maybe there you'd got an answer way sooner.

However... if I understood correctly, you are/were looking for translate text on *Select* fields with ACF & qTranslate, right? You're right about the "[ACF qTranslate](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-qtranslate/)" plugin not having a solution for *Select* fields.

I was struggling for finding a solution for this, too (that's why I strumbled upon this question!), but I just figured out one can use the markup [qTranslate](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) uses for regular text, but inside *Select* text options. Not an elegant solution, though, but it worked for me and I hope it works too for you.

For example, say you have the following options on the "Choices" field on your ACF *Select* setup (remember they go on the "Value : Label" format - the latter is what you're going to see on frontend):

```
apples : Apples
oranges : Oranges
bananas : Bananas
lemons : Lemons
```

And say you want to translate them to spanish (my native language, sorry for my bad english btw). As qTranslate follows [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) standard for its markup, you'd need `en` code for the current text, given in english, and `es` code for its spanish translation.

In order to give qTranslate a multilingual string, you need to separate each portion of each language with a prefix telling its language - that goes into squared brackets and a semicolon before its code:

[:en]Text[:es]Texto[:fr]Texte

As you'd need to translate labels, just the second column of your *Select* text options (text after semicolon) is what you need to change. So that would become

```
apples : [:en]Apples[:es]Manzanas
oranges : [:en]Oranges[:es]Naranjas
bananas : [:en]Bananas[:es]Bananos
lemons : [:en]Lemons[:es]Limones
```

Save it, and **don't forget to update the pages/blogs/whatever using those custom fields**, 'cause they changed and they're going to lose their saved values.

Hope that helps (you or whoever needs this)!

Comment: Truth is wordpress.stackexchange.com has less active users than this community. So, answers are very rare there and takes longer.